# Apps-Scripts-How to use try catch, to handle the error : "Maximum execution time exceeded error" in an onEdit(e) function, which has a limit of 30s

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

> I use two spreadsheets, `main`, which I edit, and `relationships`, which saves the codes corresponding to the edited information, to later be saved in a database
> When editing several cells at once in google Sheets, the execution time of my onEdit(e) function goes up a lot, and sometimes it exceeds the execution limit, which causes me to lose the data it would return.
> I wanted a way to, when reaching the timeout, execute the onEdit function again, so as not to lose the change data

```
var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

function onEdit(e) {
  var rowStart = e.range.rowStart;
  var rowEnd = e.range.rowEnd;
  var columnStart = e.range.columnStart;
  var columnEnd = e.range.columnEnd;
  let editouIntervalo = rowStart != rowEnd || columnStart != columnEnd ? true : false;
  let value = e.value ? e.value : "" /
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));

  if (SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('main').getName() != activeSheet.getName()) {
    return;
  }
  //Laço principal, chama as funções; vai comparar a coluna editada

  for (let colunaAlteracaoMain = columnStart; colunaAlteracaoMain <= columnEnd; colunaAlteracaoMain++) {
    for (let linhaAlteracaoMain = rowStart; linhaAlteracaoMain <= rowEnd; linhaAlteracaoMain++) {
      if (colunaAlteracaoMain == 3) {
        Logger.log("Execução de guardarMarca()")
        guardarMarca(linhaAlteracaoMain, value, editouIntervalo)
      }
  }
var relacionamento = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('relacionamento')
var valuesRelacionamento = relacionamento.getRange(`A2:F1000`).getValues();

function guardarMarca(linhaAlteracaoMain, value, editouIntervalo) {
  var marcas = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('marcas')
  var valuesMarcas = marcas.getRange(`A1:B100`).getValues();
  for (let colunaAlteracaoMain = 1; colunaAlteracaoMain <= 1000; colunaAlteracaoMain++) {
    try {
      Logger.log("Executou o try")
      if (value == "") {

        relacionamento.getRange(linhaAlteracaoMain, 1).setValue("")
        Logger.log("Excluiu valor:")
        break;
      }

      else if (valuesMarcas[colunaAlteracaoMain][1] == value) {
        relacionamento.getRange(linhaAlteracaoMain, 1).setValue(valuesMarcas[colunaAlteracaoMain][0])
        break;
      }
    }
    catch (err) {
      Logger.log("Entrou no catch")
  //o objetivo é que ao dar erro de tempo de execução, reiniciar o laço, porém não sei como fazer isso
      guardarMarca(linhaAlteracaoMain, value, editouIntervalo);
    }
  }
  Logger.log("guardarMarca() executada com sucesso.")
}
```

Comment: It's quite long for an onEdit() but you might try making it installable.  I don't think there is a time limit for installable triggers.

Comment: I would suggest you rethink your logic to use `setValues()` instead of `setValue()`.  You are executing `guardarMarca` in a double `for` loop.

Comment: Actually I see a third loop in `guardarMarca`.